# NSWindow not Activating

Tags: cocoa

I create a window in a helper tool that runs in the background (it's not an app bundle with a `.nib` and `Info.plist`, but a plain executable). When `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is called, the window is displayed but it does not "pop" out like an active window.

Can this be fixed?

Regards,
Erik

Comment: How are you making your application run in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the helper tool as a regular `.app` bundle with at least `Info.plist`. Then the problem goes away. A GUI app in OS X needs to have an `Info.plist` to receive events correctly.

The way a GUI app misbehaved if not in an app bundle has never been clear to me. If I remember correctly, it changed over time, depending on OS X's versions. I think it behaved worse in previous versions of OS X. For example, the window is shown but I couldn't click any UI inside it.

Many people who compiled a program in a cross-platform toolkit faced this problem, see e.g. [this discussion here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMac-specific_topics) in the WxWidgets wiki. Apparently, OS X doesn't mark a program not within an `.app` bundle as a foreground-able app, which causes your problem. You can use [`TransformProcessType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TransformProcessType) from your binary not inside an `.app` bundle to make a foreground-able app to solve your problem, but that's not a documented/intended usage of this function.

So, just wrap it in an `.app` bundle.

Update:

This "foreground-able-ness" is controlled by the `activationPolicy` of an app, see [this doc on `NSApplication`.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSApplicationActivationPolicy) Found the info on [this post on Cocoa with love.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html)

Comment: but when i click something in the window (e.g i have a table view there) and it becomes first responder, the window becomes active too.

Comment: I know the activation policy flag, and I actually tried it before i wrote this question. But it didn't seem to work for my problem. However I've wrapped the thing in an app bundle now, so it should be fine.